# WP JSON API get several posts using their slugs

Tags: wordpress, json-api

I have had that problem. I am using a plugin known as "Top Ten" to generate the most viewed posts. However, this plugin does not generate the posts "the WordPress way" and I am unable to retrieve a well formatted JSON output when I access a page with it. This made me decide to have a look at alternatives.

I realized I could generate the post links using this plugin. Thus, I decided to generate just the links and somehow use these links to generate a JSON response. I looked at JSON API and I found something interesting, that one can generate posts using the `get_posts` method. The documentation went further to state that "check WP_Query documentation for the full list of supported parameters" and at WP_Query documentation, I found something that I could use: `post_name_in(String [] slugs)`. This caught my attention, but I have no idea how to implement this from JSON API.

In short, what I'm looking for is a way to achieve something like this: `http://example.org/?json=get_posts&slugs=[slug-one,slug-two,slug-n]`. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's been so long but I wonder what is the solution you found.

Comment: I had to use a template page with a few lines of custom code in PHP. Not exactly the most intuitive approach but it's the only way I could get it to work.